# Recover FreeNAS network volume affected by rm -rf

Tags: macos, unix, data-recovery, freenas, file-recovery

I'm on OS X 10.8.2 and have FreeNAS 8.0 running with a 6 TB volume connected through AFP. 5 TB were recently deleted with `rm -rf` by a malicious script. The FreeNAS volume has no ZFS snapshots, because, as a first time user, I wasn't aware of this capability and the scheduling had not been set up. The volume hasn't been written to after I noticed and stopped the script. Is there any way to recover any of the data?